# jQuery pagination :contains question

Tags: jquery, list, contains

I have two unordered lists that need to be a mirrors of each other. I am using these list as a way for the user to select the size of the results they wish returned.

```
<ul>
    <li><a class='myclass selected' title='display 5'>5</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass' title='display 10'>10</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass' title='display 15'>15</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass' title='display 20'>20</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass' title='display 50'>50</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='content'></div>
<ul>
    <li><a class='myclass selected' title='display 5'>5</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass' title='display 10'>10</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass' title='display 15'>15</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass' title='display 20'>20</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass' title='display 50'>50</a></li>
</ul>
```

when one of these links is clicked I am using jquery to add a class to make the contained text bold but I need a way of adding this class to the second list. I initially thought using the contained text but when 5 is clicked 15 and 50 also have this class added I know why because they have 5 within their text, but I am stuck to remedy this.

```
$('a.myclass').live('click',function(){
   var size = $(this).text(); 
   $('a.myclass').removeclass('selected');
   $('a.myclass:contains('+size+')').addClass('selected');
});
```

The problem being

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was only on list, this would be a solution.
You could just use $(this), which is a reference to the clicked link.

```
$('a.myclass').live('click',function(){
   var size = $(this).text(); 
   $('a.myclass').removeclass('selected');
   $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

This could be a solution for the mirror list problem. (where there is two identical lists)

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li><a class='myclass size-5 selected' title='display 5'>5</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass size-10' title='display 10'>10</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass size-15' title='display 15'>15</a></li>
</ul>
<div id='content'></div>
<ul>
    <li><a class='myclass size-5 selected' title='display 5'>5</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass size-10' title='display 10'>10</a></li>
    <li><a class='myclass size-15' title='display 15'>15</a></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
$('a.myclass').live('click',function(){
   var size = $(this).text(); 
   $('a.myclass').removeclass('selected');
   $('size-'+size).addClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: The first line `var size ...` is obsolete then.

Comment: sorry guys I don't think I stated the question clearly I have tried again please not the edits

Comment: this will not solve the mirrored problem as this only refers to the clicked item.

Comment: Is it possible to add an extra class like, size-5, size-10 etc to the elemets? In that case you could use $(".size-" + size).addClass('selected');

Comment: I am currently looking at using toggleClass but am again stuck with what the condition should be.